# Issue with Mercurial and third-party hg-login script

Tags: linux, perl, mercurial, cvs, centos

I'm trying to setup mercurial using the HgLogin  I have the following problem system. I done everything that is needed but when I tried to login to my repository I receive this answer:

```
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 1: use: command not found
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 1:
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 2:
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 3: {PATH}: command not found
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 3:
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 4:
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 5: my: command not found
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 5:
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 6: my: command not found
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 6:
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 7:
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 11:
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 12: my: command not found
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 12:
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 13: my: command not found
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 13:
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 14:
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 18:
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 19: my: command not found
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 19:
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 20: my: command not found
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 20: : command not found
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 20:
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 21:
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 25:
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 26: defined: command not found
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 27: or: command not found
: command not foundrial/hg-login: line 27:
remote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `$user'
'emote: /home/mercurial/hg-login: line 28: `my ($user) = $user_in =~ /^($r_user)$/
```

It seems Perl won't parse the script.
You can find the hglogin script on https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgLogin

Comment: please use syntax formatting :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need this at the top of your perl script:

```
#!/bin/perl
```

or the path to your system perl.  It looks like your system is running that script as if it were a shell script not a perl script.